# Javascript alert not staying in Mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript, jsp, firefox, alert

I wrote an alert which comes on change of a dropdown. It comes for a particular value selected on the dropdown. The alert is working fine in IE, but in Mozilla it stays for a moment and disappears.

Below is the code for alert which gets called on `onchange` of a dropdown.

```
function psychAlert()
{
    var element = document.getElementById("service_help");
    for (var x = 0; x <element.options.length; x++) {
        if (element.options[x].selected) {
            selectedVal = element.options[x].value;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(selectedVal == '1514'){
        alert("Please call Helpline");
    }
}
```

Below is the dropdown code where the alert is getting called from a onchange.

```
<html:select tabindex="<%= tabIndex.getNext()%>" property="serviceDesc" size="1" styleId="service_help" onchange="javascript:  psychAlert(); " ></html:option>
    html:optionsCollection property="serviceDescList" value="lookupCode" label="shortDescription"/>
<html:select>
```

Comment: Your select is very wonky, is there a reason you wrote it this way?

Comment: no there is no particular reason for that.

Comment: If that answer works for you, make sure you accept it please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your example doesn't include the actual data within your dropdown list, I cleaned it up and made an example that's much easier to follow and should clarify any issues you're having. This code has been tested in IE 8, Firefox, and Chrome, and works without fail in all three.

```js
var example = document.getElementById("dlExample");

example.addEventListener("change", function() {
  if (example.value === "3") {
    alert("Please call the help desk.");
  }
});
```

```html
<select id="dlExample">
  <option value="0">Hi</option>
  <option value="1">Bye</option>
  <option value="2">Yes</option>
  <option value="3">No</option>
</select>
```

So looking at this code. First, we simplified your very convoluted and overly done `select`. Now you're no longer calling an onchange within the code, storing the value there, or requiring needless loops. A simple `select` with all of your options.

As for the javascript, we started by first adding a simple `EventListener` by finding the `select` with a `getElementsByID` (note that I set the ID in the `select`, the name wouldn't won't work). After that, we set the `EventLIstener` to be based off a change event. Anyone a change happens to that dropdown, it will check and verify that the dropdown value is whatever  you wanted the alert to be called upon. Sometimes simple is better, and in this case, even more so.

Comment: @Vishwa You can run the code snippet by pressing the `Run code snippet` button. It'll bring up a little example html window with the control in it.

Comment: For the code what i posted this is the select code where i am calling the alert.                                                                                                <html:select tabindex="<%= tabIndex.getNext()%>" property="serviceDesc" size="1" styleId="service_desc" onchange="javascript:psychAlert() ;" >
           <html:option value="">&nbsp;</html:option>
           <html:optionsCollection property="serviceDescList" value="lookupCode" label="shortDescription"/>
          </html:select>

Comment: @Vishwa So simplify it like I demonstrated in my snippet. You don't need to use `<html:option value="">`, you can just use `<option>`.

Comment: @Vishwa If you insist on doing it through Apache, you can still use the javascript code, just change the id in the `getElementByID` to "service_desc" instead, and change the value being compared to "1514". You can also set the `selectedVal` variable to `example.value`.

Comment: @Vishwa Great, if you'd please click the checkbox by my answer to accept it, that'd be great!